# Get extracts from a MySQL full text search

Tags: mysql, string-matching

I'm using MySQL to implement a search feature on a website (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). 
The query itself was not too difficult to write, it will look more or less like this :

```
SELECT 
    document_id, 
    content, 
    MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('test foo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM document 
WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('test foo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY score ASC
```

But now I want to show to the user an extract of the document where the terms he searched for matched (like in google), for example, if he searched for "cloud mysql", I want to show something like this for each results :

> ...  In previous post we talk how to deploy **Cloud** Foundry on your
>   local machine. Today I want to share some experience how to deploy
>   **MySQL** ...

What the best way to do this ?